# Как сделать сканнер QR-кода на сайте средствами фронтенда?

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

Есть необходимость сделать сканнер QR-кода на сайте наподобие [этого сервиса](https://webqr.com/).

Задача: есть кнопка при нажатии на которую включается либо веб-камера, либо камера на мобильном (в зависимости от того, с чего зашел пользователь), ну и наводится и считывается.

Кто-нибудь делал подобное? Есть референсы? Репозитории видели какие-нибудь на гитхабе?

Comment: Гуглятся по javascript QR scanner.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian для java и objective c да, вы правы.

Comment: Первая [ссылка](https://github.com/LazarSoft/jsqrcode) по этому запросу дает репозитарий на гитхабе, как раз от вашего [примера](https://webqr.com/).